# Ftp user defined jars to maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a maven project i need to copy the jar files from a ftp server to the lib folder during the mvn clean install task.

Suggest me the plugins or steps to achieve this.

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that .because Maven resolves its dependencies via HTTP,
you can deploy via ftp but not  resolve the dependencies

Comment: This is not true. Maven resolves its dependencies via _repositories_. Those can be configured to hit a URL through HTTP, or use FTP, or even be local file based without any external communication.